# customise a specific column in ZK charts

Tags: zk

i m working on a project using ZK charts Using MVC  approach,  what i want to do exactly is to change the background or to add a guideline ( with diffrent color) to a specific column for example the one with index 3 : where is what i do want to achieve

here is my chart :

[image: normal chart]

and here is what i want with diffrent color in column with index 3 :

[image: column with diffrent color]

or with a guide line ( green color):

[image: with a guide line]

is this possible in Zk ? and thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful this gonna be to you, i found this example about ZK charts, as the example shows in the model class it manages the colors as public static values, so, maybe you're managing the color in a similar way. here,

https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/chart/bar_chart

Then, if you wanna change a specific color of a bar, this example gives you a hint how to do it.